# Zero in input data causes infeasible linear optimisation for a linear regression with a margin over slope

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, or-tools

I am using [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) in Python for a simple optimisation problem of parameters of a linear regression.

Let me present you a **simplified** version of my problem:
The general formula is: `y = [a,m]*x`, only slope, no intercept. However, the slope has a "margin" *m* which means that we are in fact looking at a range `[a-m, a+m]`. Given some input vector *X* and expected output vector *y* my task is to infer parameters *a* and *m* such that all expected *yi* fall inside their respective inferred ranges upon regression (these are my constraints) and *m* is minimal (that is the objective function).

Here is a toy example:

```
>>> from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
>>> solver = pywraplp.Solver('RegressionWithMargin', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
>>> a = solver.NumVar(-solver.infinity(), solver.infinity(), 'a')
>>> m = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), 'm')
>>> for x_i, y_i in zip([1, 2, 3, -1], [1, 3, 5, -2]):
...   solver.Add(a*x_i - m * abs(x_i) <= y_i)
...   solver.Add(a*x_i + m * abs(x_i) >= y_i)
...
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2bc60> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b300> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a282d0> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2bf90> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b9c0> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2bdb0> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b7e0> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2bba0> >
>>> solver.Minimize(m)
>>> solver.Solve()
0
>>> a.solution_value()
1.5
>>> m.solution_value()
0.5
```

This is all good.

However, I am running into a problem while substituting the last *Xi* to zero:

```
>>> solver = pywraplp.Solver('Fuzzyregression', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
>>> a = solver.NumVar(-solver.infinity(), solver.infinity(), 'a')
>>> m = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), 'm')
>>> for x_i, y_i in zip([1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 3, 5, -2]): # HERE
...   solver.Add(a*x_i - m * abs(x_i) <= y_i)
...   solver.Add(a*x_i + m * abs(x_i) >= y_i)
...
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b1e0> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b330> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2bae0> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2bd50> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b810> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b570> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2b870> >
<ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp.Constraint; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'operations_research::MPConstraint *' at 0x7f90c3a2bfc0> >
>>> solver.Minimize(m)
>>> solver.Solve()
2
>>> a.solution_value()
E1024 00:41:36.461660 14584 linear_solver.cc:1869] No solution exists. MPSolverInterface::result_status_ = MPSOLVER_INFEASIBLE
0.0
>>> m.solution_value()
E1024 00:41:41.611743 14584 linear_solver.cc:1869] No solution exists. MPSolverInterface::result_status_ = MPSOLVER_INFEASIBLE
0.0
```

Could someone please explain to me what is going on and what should I adjust for a proper parameter inference?
Is that because for `x=0` the slope goes away in the constraint and I have no "marginalised intercept"?

#### EDIT:

My concrete question is: if adding a marginalised intercept would solve the issue, how should I adjust the code?

Comment: You said that you are looking for solution without intercept which implies that when x is 0 y should be 0. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: in the last iteration, you add the constraint a * 0 - 0 <= -2, which is infeasible

Comment: I added an edit with a concrete question specified